# Spring RequestMapping in RestController returns 406

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, http-status-code-406

Inside `@RestController` I have a  `@RequestMapping` which works except I'm getting 406 in client while trying to return POJO class `ResponseVO`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "path", method = RequestMethod.POST
            , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> path(

...
ResponseVO responseVO = new responseVO();
return new ResponseEntity<>(responseVO, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I'm sending POST with JSON body, My request headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 58
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6 (Java/1.8.0_151)
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1067
```

Comment: Is `responseVO` extends `GenericResponse`?

Comment: First of all, remove `@ResponseBody` annotation from method because it's already included in `@RestController` annotation. Also remove `produces` attribute from `@RequestMapping` and check if issue gone.

Comment: @FimaTaf yes it is

Comment: Try changing the value of request header `Accept` to `application/json`

Comment: @aLeX I tried and same response

Comment: can you post the full path of the URL you are posting to ?

Comment: @Fabulous is it relevant ? I'm able to debug it and gets to return statement

Comment: Perhaps you missed out the leading slash.....before "path"

Comment: @KamilW. somehow after your change I get status code 200, can you explain?

Comment: @user7294900 You did my both suggestion ? I guess the solution was in removing `produces` attribute and in that case spring will automaticly detect response content type, but it's only my gues. Can you mark my answer as solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove `@ResponseBody` annotation from method because it's already included in `@RestController` annotation. Also remove `produces` attribute from `@RequestMapping` and check if issue gone.

Answer (score 3):

when you use `@RestController` it automatically means that you are annotating `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`in spring boot. So you do not explicitly need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation on your method. Also `@ResponseBody` annotation is added above the method not with the method declaration. So even if you add this annotation properly your code should work fine. take a look below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "path", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody 
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> path(

...
    ResponseVO responseVO = new responseVO();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseVO, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set a `consumes` property in `@RequestMapping`.

But you can use `@PostMapping` for JSON instead, there are all values will be set by default.

just `@PostMapping("path")`